# Apache Poi identify formula with reference to another workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a workbook, which I must clear from all references to other workbooks. I am currently trying to parse the cell formulas wo check if they are referencing any excel file.

For that I use this line

```
cell.getCellFormula().matches(".*\\[.*\\.xls[xm]?\\].*")
```

the issue with this is, that the cell looks like this in XML format:

```
 <c r="K64" s="2128">
    <f>[5]Segments!$AS$7/Annual!AF38</f>
    <v>0.0</v>
 </c>
```

As you can see, the formula doesn't actually contain `.xls`, '.xlsx' or `.xlsm` at all. As far as I know `[5]` indicates a shared string which holds the actual path and therefore the actual value for the formula.

Now one could say and change the regex to `.*\\[\d+\\].*`, but I think that this can be pretty error prone. Also I think that not literally every external reference will look like this.

So my question is:

**How can I identify formulas which reference an external workbook?**

---

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

EDIT:

I have prepared an sample excel file showcasing the issue. It's available for download at [workupload.com](https://workupload.com/file/gr4EYkHS)

Comment: Did you look in the shared XML for the id 5? In these cases: the simpler, the better. Even if erroneous.

Comment: @JoopEggen In no XML file I could find the actual file name. I used a test file and not the actual file, but the result should be the same. And if not, it just adds another layer of complexity

Comment: Maybe, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370277/dynamically-add-external-cross-workbook-references) holds some hints on how to do that. The code in the accepted (and bountied) answer works with formulae and external sheets.

Comment: @deHaar The answer lets me list all external references, but so far I couldn't find a way to match the numbers (`[5]`) to the reference

Comment: The xlsx unzipped, `xl/sharedStrings.xml` the text should be in XML element `/sst/si[5]/t`

Comment: @JoopEggen its not available there at all. Neither that XML element nor the text. I actually found the file name in `\xl\externalLinks\_rels\externalLink1.xml.rels`, but still couldn't make a connection between the number and the file name

Comment: I have prepared an sample excel file. Included the link for the download in the question

Comment: Does `org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ExternalLinksTable` not give you what you need? That's what XSSF uses internally when matching those for formula evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way shown in [Dynamically add External (Cross-Workbook) references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370277/dynamically-add-external-cross-workbook-references/32586459#32586459) definitely is the way to go. Go through all formula tokens and if one of those has an external sheet index, then this formula refers an external sheet.

Example using your uploaded file:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.EvaluationWorkbook.ExternalSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFEvaluationWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class ExcelReadExternalReference {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filePath = "TestExternalLinks.xlsx";
        // String filePath = "TestExternalLinks.xls";

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));

        EvaluationWorkbook evalWorkbook = null;
        if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
            evalWorkbook = HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((HSSFWorkbook) workbook);
        } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
            evalWorkbook = XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((XSSFWorkbook) workbook);
        }

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        EvaluationSheet evalSheet = evalWorkbook.getSheet(0);

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                    String cellFormula = cell.getCellFormula();
                    System.out.println(cellFormula);

                    EvaluationCell evaluationCell = evalSheet.getCell(cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex());
                    Ptg[] formulaTokens = evalWorkbook.getFormulaTokens(evaluationCell);
                    for (Ptg formulaToken : formulaTokens) {
                        int externalSheetIndex = -1;
                        if (formulaToken instanceof Ref3DPtg) {
                            Ref3DPtg refToken = (Ref3DPtg) formulaToken;
                            externalSheetIndex = refToken.getExternSheetIndex();
                        } else if (formulaToken instanceof Area3DPtg) {
                            Area3DPtg refToken = (Area3DPtg) formulaToken;
                            externalSheetIndex = refToken.getExternSheetIndex();
                        } else if (formulaToken instanceof Ref3DPxg) {
                            Ref3DPxg refToken = (Ref3DPxg) formulaToken;
                            externalSheetIndex = refToken.getExternalWorkbookNumber();
                        } else if (formulaToken instanceof Area3DPxg) {
                            Area3DPxg refToken = (Area3DPxg) formulaToken;
                            externalSheetIndex = refToken.getExternalWorkbookNumber();
                        }

                        if (externalSheetIndex >= 0) {
                            System.out.print("We have extrenal sheet index: " + externalSheetIndex
                                    + ". So this formula refers an external sheet in workbook: ");

                            ExternalSheet externalSheet = null;
                            if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
                                externalSheet = evalWorkbook.getExternalSheet(externalSheetIndex);
                            } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
                                externalSheet = evalWorkbook.getExternalSheet(null, null, externalSheetIndex);
                            }
                            String linkedFileName = externalSheet.getWorkbookName();
                            System.out.println(linkedFileName);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        workbook.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, it was my bad for not testing all the code. I only bothered with the `getReferencedWorkbooksXssf` method. As this seems to work just fine (no performance test yet), I wanted to clean up the code. Therefore the following question I am not certain about. do `Ref3DPtg` and `Area3DPtg` only occur within `.xls` workbooks **or** do they only refer to an `.xls` workbook? Because if they can only occur in `.xls`, then I am confident I can remove them, else I would need to leave that in

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Yes, the `ptg` (parse thing) is a binary `BIFF` (`HSSF`)concept while `pxg` is a special kind of Ptg which is `XSSF` only.